# Accessing WinRT APIs from within .NET core app running as service in Windows 11

Tags: windows, .net-core, windows-services, windows-runtime, windows-11

I'm trying to read the title from the current media session in Windows 10/11.

The following example runs fine if I execute it from within the IDE or manually start the published .exe from console.

But once I register the published .exe as a service in Windows and start it I get the following error:

> The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (0x80070424)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in [...]\Program.cs:line 5

`Program.cs`:

```
using Windows.Media.Control;

try 
{
    var sm = await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync();  
    var session = sm.GetCurrentSession(); 
    var props = await session.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync();  

    while (true)  {    
        File.AppendAllText("[...]/log.txt", props?.Title + "\n");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    File.AppendAllText("[...]/log.txt", e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace + "\n");
}
```

`.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Commands used to publish and register service:

```
dotnet publish .\winrttest\ -c Debug -r win-x64 -f net6.0-windows10.0.22000.0 -o C:\[...] --no-self-contained
.\sc.exe create testservice binpath="C:\[...]\winrttest.exe"
```

How can I access the `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager` while running as a Windows service?

I've already tried this example on multiple machines.

While `.exe` runs fine as Windows service on my main PC, it fails on all other machines I've tested.

I can't figure out the exact setting or whatever it is that allows this to work on my main PC but not on the other machines.

I already tried installing the latest .NET SDK on the other machines, but that does not help either.

---

**UPDATE**:

After a bit more testing it seems like this is an issue exclusive to Windows 11.
I've tested on 3 different devices running windows 10 and it runs fine on all of them.
I've also tested on 4 different devices that are running windows 11 and it fails on all of them.

This finally also explains why it always ran fine on my main PC, as that one is still on Windows 10.

So how to access the `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager` in Windows 11 while running as a service?

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Turns out this is caused by a change in Windows 11, as Universal Windows Platform (UWP) APIs are no longer supported when running in a non-interactive session (as a service or as SYSTEM).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1263190/can-not-access-globalsystemmediatransportcontrolss

Comment: I've tested your code in a Windows service and it works fine w/o any special config (configured as local system). The error you mention 0x80070424 (ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST) means there's a problem with the service itself, not with the specific code you show. Please post a fully reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier did you test on Windows 10 or 11? As far as I can tell from the devices I've tested, this issue seems to only occur in Windows 11 (see my last update).

Comment: Ok I reproduce in Windows 11. What I think happens is the error comes indirectly from the code *inside* `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager` which only opens the "AudioSrv" service https://i.imgur.com/EkKRwTH.png and for some reason that fails with ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST when running in a service in Windows 11 (it works in regular programs). You could report to Microsoft.